# Internal clock reset after some time with no battery on GoPro Hero 3+ Black

Tags: battery, gopro, time, battery-drain

I am using GoPro Hero 3+ Black and wondering if anyone experiences the same issue: After some time with no battery left (more than 1 hour but approx. less than 24 hours) the GoPro resets its internal clock to 2012-01-01 00:00:00. It really bothers me when I am in the wilderness and have to set the clock each day or if I forgot that and then have to sync files with my other cameras manually. So does anyone experience similar issue? and after what duration of time does your GoPro with no battery reset its internal clock?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question over on http://video.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one internal battery, which take care about the clock. Check please [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/GoPro+Hero3+Teardown/12457) web page, step 13, right image. If this battery is discharged (it is not rechargeable) lost of settings as clock is expected behavior. IMHO there is no way to change it by self, so my humble recommendation is to contact GoPro service

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same thing here in the gopro Hero 3 white edition.
The internal clock resets very fast, from the moment i take out the battery. 
As far i can remmember that clock problem started with the latest and most recent firmware update on the GP3 in 2014 (check GP-site). I asume that the firmware update did kill the internal battery (and clock), yes i did notice this a month after updating. 
Now i use the camera with a powersource Always on, which means i can only switch a external battery without being connected to something that feeds the power when switching the battery, or having it constant connected to a usb powersource.
So check when you had the last update on your hero 3+ and when the problem started.

Or...on some devices with an SD-card this type clock storage works with a file that remembers the date/time. Instead of prying it open switching SD-cards can maybe fix this problem.

Cheers.